# ARC Semantic issue: No known class method for selector 'componentsWithLink:domain:'

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am stuck with an issue since past 5+ hours, I am working on a react native project of version 0.59.0, it is a 1.5 years old project and it is working fine on android, but when building it for iOS, I was facing many issues one of which was:

> ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore

So to make it work, I included arm64 in excluded architecture and my build started working on simulator but my IPA was not working on a real device, again after removing arm64 and resolving multiple issues, I am stuck with the following issue which is coming in RNFirebaseLinks.m file as :

> ARC Semantic Issue Group: No known class method for selector 'componentsWithLink:domain:'

Also sharing my device specifications:

> macos: Macbook pro(11.0.1), chip: Apple M1,
> Xcode version: 12.4

PodFile content:

```
**# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project**
platform :ios, '10.0'
target 'PropertiesPublisherNew' do
**# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks**
#use_frameworks!
**# Pods for PropertiesPublisherNew**
pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.3.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
**# pod 'RNReanimated', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated'**
**# pod 'RNScreens', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-screens'**
**# pod 'react-native-netinfo', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo'**
#pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
target 'PropertiesPublisherNewTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
**# Pods for testing**
end
end
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
end
end
target 'PropertiesPublisherNew-tvOS' do
**# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks**
**# use_frameworks!**
**# Pods for PropertiesPublisherNew-tvOS**
target 'PropertiesPublisherNew-tvOSTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
**# Pods for testing**
end
end
```

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score -1):

Add pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.15.0' in PodFile inside IOS Folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).